# Plot with Wolfram Alpha Scientific Data

Tags: plotting, curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries, natural-language

Now that Mathematica has already embedded Wolfram Alpha, so I'd like to plot a graph: `"Air Density" - "Elevation"`.

I know that

[image: input]

yields

[image: output]

But I can't do that 10000 times. Is there any convenient way to do that? Such as `Range[0,10000]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can just use `StandardAtmosphereData[]` instead:

```
ρ = Table[QuantityMagnitude[StandardAtmosphereData[Quantity[h, "Meters"], "Density"]],
          {h, 0, 10^4, 10}];

ListLinePlot[ρ, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
             FrameLabel -> {"Height (m)", "Density (kg/m³"}]
```

[image: density vs. height plot for air]